# How to determine whether swift package is running from remote background notification?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Swift Package and want to disable any network requests if the host app has been woken up by a remote background notification.

I can detect whether the app is in the background or not. However, it needs to specifically be from a notification, rather than someone just backgrounding the app.

I know in an app you could check for `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)` to determine a remote background notification. But I can't detect that unless I have an App Delegate, can I?

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in way to detect that. You need to have a `Bool` injected into the starting point of your framework to decide whether the app was launched from a remote notification or not.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Oh so this `Bool` would be provided by the developer who uses my swift package? Also, do you know whether a background notification can cause network requests associated with the launch of an app to happen? My framework is config'd on launch of the app, and I don't want network reqs in my framework going off when that happens in the bg due to a notification. I'm kind of assuming it can happen but not 100% certain!

Comment: Yes, it would be provided by the consumer of your package. Yes, an app can launch network requests when reacting to a push notification (even if silent push). Tbh I don't think you should try to handle turning off networking on the SDK level depending on how the app was launched, since you cannot reliably detect that - it's always up to the consumer of your package to correctly handle launching.

Comment: So instead of trying to stop networking in certain conditions, I would suggest creating a clear interface and documentation for your package and letting the consumer decide if they really want to turn off networking in certain cases and if so, giving them an easy and safe option for doing so.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Do the network requests need to be specifically specified by the dev when reacting to the push notification though? Or does the "whole app" wake up and act as if its in the foreground and starts running reqs as it normally would when it receives a bg push notification?